# Eclipse/Tomcat constantly crashing on SESSIONS.ser

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

This has been driving me nuts. When I save something, Tomcat sporadically crashes with the following error... Edit JSP or Java files. Save your work. Then maybe a 25% probability of a crash... The clue here is that it works correctly most of the time.

After it crashes, a simple server restart fixes it again.

I've Googled it to death.

- I understand is has to do with saving the sessions for reload between restarts. But while developing, this is a big help. So I don't want to disable it.
- I understand that it sounds like a folder permission problem. But it works fine most of the time. i.e. I can watch the folder in Explorer and see the file SESSIONS.ser appear and disappear correctly. And it usually doesn't blow up.
- I have verified that the whole related Workspace folder structure is excluded from AV and Backup software.

But still... Constant crashing.

Please help. I'm out of ideas...

Thanks

Using: Eclipse Kepler, Tomcat 7.0.45, Java 1.7.0_45-b18 64 bit, Windows 7 Pro 64 bit, 16GB RAM.

```
Feb 11, 2014 11:00:15 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager doUnload
SEVERE: IOException while saving persisted sessions: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\Tomcat\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\_\SESSIONS.ser (The system cannot find the path specified)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\Tomcat\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\_\SESSIONS.ser (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5622)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3947)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Feb 11, 2014 11:00:15 AM org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager stopInternal
SEVERE: Exception unloading sessions to persistent storage
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Workspace\Tomcat\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\_\SESSIONS.ser (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5622)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3947)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1345)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1530)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1519)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Did you the check the path for existence?

Comment: Sure. It exists and you can watch the file show up and disappear (when it doesn't crash).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding metadata-complete="true" to your web.xml and restart tomcat. It has solved another missing file problem of mine but I am still not sure why it worked for me.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5" metadata-complete="true">
```